# Chance constrained optimization - interpretation

Tags: stochastic-programming, chance-constraints

Suppose that we have a stochastic vector $\psi$ and $S$ realisations of $\psi$ given by $\psi_1,\dots,\psi_S$ with equal probability of occurrence. In addition, we have constraints of the form
\begin{equation}
h_i(x,\psi)\leq b_i,\quad \forall i=1,...,m
\end{equation}
for the decision vector $x$.

A *joint chance constraint* is then given by
\begin{equation}
P(\  h_i(x,\psi)\leq b_i , \quad \forall i=1,..,m\ )\geq \alpha 
\end{equation}
stating that we can accept that some (or all) of these constraints are violation with a probability of $1-\alpha$. We could also write *single chance constraints* as follows
\begin{equation}
P(\  h_i(x,\psi)\leq b_i \ )\geq \alpha, \quad \forall i=1,..,m
\end{equation}
stating that we will accept violations of the individual constraints with a probability of $1-\alpha$. Using binary variables $z^s$ equalling 0 *iff* all constraints are satisfied in realisation $s$, we can formulate the joint chance constraint as the MIP
\begin{align}
h_i(x,\psi_s)\leq b_i+Mz^s,&&\forall i=1,...,m,s=1,...,S\\
\sum_{s=1}^Sz^s\leq \lfloor (1-\alpha)S\rfloor
\end{align}

Using binary variables $z^s_i$ equalling 0 *iff* constraint $i$ is statisfied in realisation $s$ we can formulate the single chance constraint version as follows:
\begin{align}
&h_i(x,\psi_s)\leq b_i+Mz^s_i,&&\forall i=1,...,m,s=1,...,S\\
&\sum_{s=1}^Sz^s_i\leq \lfloor (1-\alpha)S\rfloor,&&\forall i=1,...,m
\end{align}

My question is, what is the interpretation of the following MIP
\begin{align}
&h_i(x,\psi_s)\leq b_i+Mz^s_i,&&\forall i=1,...,m,s=1,...,S\\
&\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{s=1}^Sz^s_i\leq \lfloor (1-\alpha)S\rfloor
\end{align}
Does it have some sensible interpretation?

Comment: I just fixed your deterministic equivalent constraints as they were missing the multiplication of probability of each scenario by each constraint violation variable. If this was not a typo, then perhaps this was the issue confusing you about the constraint interpretation.

Comment: @Ehsan I am no expert in stochastic optimization, but isn't the probability present in the form of $1/S$ on the right hand side? So an implicit equal probability of all realisation?

Comment: @Sune Yeah, you're right. I didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: @Ehsan thanks for adding the "with equal probability of occurrence". I see that it is not at all obvious from the original question.

Comment: @Djames Is the last set of constraints something you came up with or you read it somewhere? I cannot see a sensible interpretation. Perhaps, if you multiply the right-hand-side by $m$ then you might read it as constraining the probability that any of the constraints in any of the scenarios is violated.

Comment: @k88074 Actually, it was just a stray thought. After implementing  the single chance constraint version wrongly, in the way I ask about, I just wondered whether it had any interpretation.